# Merge CSV files with filtering

Tags: csv, powershell

I've started to play around with PowerShell some time ago, in order to filter some logs one of my servers is creating.

The individual log is a CSV in text file, where first line is some info about the process creating it. Headers are on the 2nd line, and the actual things are on the 3rd. There are about 15 properties, but I only need couple of them.

Here is what works for me flawlessly on one file:

```
Import-csv file.txt | Select-Object -Skip 1 -Property prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4, prop5 | Export-csv result.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

But, whatever I tried to use for multiple files (let's say, all .txt files in said folder, since the logs are created per day, and grouped in folders), it doesn't work for me, and I suspect it's because of the different first line, which I try to skip the same way, but I then get empty merged CSV file with only prop1 as 1st column

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If the headers are actually on the second line, not the first, then you should probably do

```
Get-Content file.txt | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ConvertFrom-Csv | Export-Csv result.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Because this strips the first line before it gets parsed as CSV.

If you want to merge multiple files in the same way, you can do that similarly:

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Content $_ | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ConvertFrom-Csv
} | Export-Csv result.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: That's helpful, but when I try to apply the following: [code] (Get-ChildItem *.txt | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Content $_ | Select-Object -Skip 1 -Property prop1, prop2, prop3 | ConvertFrom-Csv
} | Export-Csv result.csv -NoTypeInformation) it's not giving me what I want basically. Of course, I can then take the result.csv and do the Select-Object by property in next line

Comment: You can add the properties you need to the `select` call in the pipeline there. No need to import the written file again.

Comment: That's not working for me, I get a nonsense CSV when I add `Select-Object -Skip 1 -Property prop1, prop2, prop3`